# What do you think about Google algorithm changes?

Tags: google

What is the best SEO software to analyze websites and make the necessary on-page changes ?

Comment: And both questions are opinion based...

Answer (score 1):

It's too hard to say, but I personally use the following SEO Tools:

- BrightLocal
- MySEOTool
- WebMeUp

I like MySEOTool as far as ease of use, and speed. I like BrightLocal as far as the tools like Citation Finder, and Google Places competitive analysis, but overall WebMeUp is by far the most extensive tool and most powerful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Google algorithm changes is a must needed one and i don't think too
   much about those changes because if you work for users and not for
   Google, you don't need to worry about that changes.
2. There are so many SEO tools to analyze a website but not all the
   tools are Good. I always prefer http://moz.com/tools but i don't
   sure about the results.
3. In order to know about the on-page methods, go through this post
   http://www.searchenginejournal.com/on-page-optimization-a-complete-walkthrough/6746/